# MySQL C# Query using MySql.Data.MySqlClient::MySqlCommand string format issue

Tags: c#, mysql, database, apache, xampp

Having SQL formatting issues which I believe is due to my sql query not being structured correctly, specifically the quotation marks.

```
        string recordedPassword = SQLReader.RunQuery (
            "SELECT " +
            "Password " +
            "FROM " +
            "players " +
            "WHERE " +
            "Username="+
            "\""+
            username +
            "\""+
            "Password=" +
            "\""+
            password +
            "\"");
```

I know double-quotation marks are done by putting a backslash before the quotation mark to make it a literal string character but when I look at it while debugging it still shows the backslash which makes me think it isn't working.

I've read a number of users online say mySQL queries should use single qutation marks to define values, but when testing queries on PhpMyAdmit it only accepted values in double quotation marks.

*Double*

[image]

*Single*

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If whatever `SQLReader` is accepts parameterized queries then do that.

Comment: It's the apostrophe in `Anthony's` that's breaking your single quote version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to address/review here

You can make multiline strings more readable in C# by prefixing them with @:

```
string sql = @"SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE field = value";
```

This stops the "newline in constant" error, as well as making a few other things not require \escaping with a backslash. Because the stirng is now allowed to contain newlines, you dont have to stop and start it with " " + " " + " " all the time, so it doesnt look as messy. It does disable things like being able to use \n for newline, because \ is just treated as a normal character. It thus makes windows paths cleaner to type too (@"C:\temp" vs "C:\temp". SQL doesn't care about whitespace so indent your C# however you like

That said, you'd be better off putting your SQL strings in a resource/settings file, or even going the whole hog and using a data access library like entity framework, so you're not writing SQL in strings at all

Always parameterize your statements. If you aren't going to use EF or similar (which will parameterize for you), you should definitely at least be using:

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = @u and password = @p";
```

Later, set the Parameter values on your SqlCommand (or whatever), so that @u has a value of "Anthony" and @p has "Anthony's password". Never, ever build SQL strings by concatenating together as you have done here - it's not only a bug risk as soon as someone uses an apostrophe, it's a security risk. See http://bobby-tables.com for more info

Most database vendors use apostrophe ' to start and end a string, not double quotes ". MySQL might be an exception, but do try to follow the convention rather than learning proprietary SQL syntaxes. SQL isn't like javascript, where both " and ' mean "string" and you "use whichever one allows you to have have values containing the other one" like `"Antony's password"` or `'she said "yes" already'`

In SQL, if you want to put an apostrophe in a string, you generally double it up: `WHERE password = 'Anthony''s password'` but of you're using parameters (always use parameters) you don't have to do this

Comment: Ah yeah, got it working now. Using SQLParameters and StringBuilder did the trick. Cheers!